# Does the cocoon gem require n models to be built in the controller new action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-cocoon

I have installed the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) in my rails 4 app exactly as described. This works fantastic in the parent model form allowing the user to add/remove fields for the child model(s).  Where I'm having trouble is the submission of the child object.  If child models are built in the parent model's new action, then I am able to submit exactly however many models were created, no more. This is obvious from the parameters being submitted as they contain child_attributes (or not, if no child models were built in the controller).

Currently running

rails 4.2.10

ruby 2.5.1

cocoon 1.2.14

jquery-rails 4.3.3

jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1

CODE SNIPPETS

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event.competitions.build
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.create(event_params)
    if @event.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Event created"
      redirect_to events_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Event not created.  Please check for errors in the form and try again."
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(
                                  :event_name,
                                  :event_start,
                                  :event_end,
                                  :event_address,
                                  competitions_attributes: [:id, :competition_name, :maximum_participants, :type_id, :fee, :_destroy]
    )
  end
end
```

Parent model

```
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :competitions, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :event
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :competitions, allow_destroy: true
```

Child model

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :type
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, allow_destroy: true
```

Form (new.html.erb)

```
  <div class="text-left ">
    <%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :event_name, input_html: {maxlength: 60} %>
        <%= f.input :logo, label: "Event Logo:", hint: 'jpg or png files allowed, max size: 1MB' %>
        <a <%= f.input :description, label_html: {class: "glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign event-new", href: "#", 'data-content': "You can format your description using the editor buttons. Cutting and pasting from other text editors will not work unless they are first exported into html format. For security reasons, some html tags are not allowed and will be removed.", rel: "popover", "data-placement": 'top', 'data-original-title': 'WYSIWYG editor help', 'data-trigger': 'hover' }, as: :ckeditor, input_html: { ckeditor: { toolbar: 'mini' } } %></a>
        <%= f.input :event_address, placeholder: "Enter Street Address, City, State, Postal Code" %>
        <%= f.input :registration_fee, :input_html => { :value => '0.00'}, label: "Team registration fee" %>


        <%= f.input :event_start %>
        <%= f.input :event_end %>
        <br />
        <h3>Competitions</h3>
        <div id="competitions">
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :competitions do |competition| %>
            <%= render 'competition_fields', f: competition %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'add competition', f, :competitions %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit 'Create', :class => 'pull-right btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
  </div
```

Partial (named _competition_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :competition_name %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:type_id, @types, :id, :name, prompt: "Select a Type") %>
  <%= f.input :fee, :input_html => { :value => '0.00'} %>
  <%= f.input :maximum_participants %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Delete Competition", f %>
</div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require google_analytics
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .
```

[image: Image of the partial component in the form, note 2 competitions submitted]

From the Rails console (after the parent model is inserted)

```
"competitions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"competition_name"=>"test1", "type_id"=>"2", "fee"=>"0.00", "maximum_participants"=>"8", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create"}

  SQL (17.4ms)  INSERT INTO "competitions" ("competition_name", "maximum_participants", "type_id", "fee", "event_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["competition_name", "test1"], ["maximum_participants", 8], ["type_id", 2], ["fee", "0.0"], ["event_id", 305], ["created_at", "2019-08-01 11:13:44.582299"], ["updated_at", "2019-08-01 11:13:44.582299"]]
```

I've been through all the usual issues with the setup for the gem (accepts_nested_attributes_for, inverse_of, the naming and indentation of the child_fields partial, jQuery is installed and cocoon being called etc.) It's all to spec so far as I can tell.  And it works, as long as the child models are built in the new action.

Comment: Ya you have to 'build' at least one child in the new action for the form fields to show up. You would need to do that regardless of the cocoon gem afaik. What the cocoon gem does is dynamically add more fields. Then you need the nested params as well. What do your strong params look like and what do the params look like coming in?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mike.  The strong params include the child-fields and match what gets submitted, but only when the child model(s) are built in the new action.  If I don’t create a child then nothing gets returned even if I add the fields in the form.  What’s a bit surprising is there’s no mention of this requirement in the gem, nor is it present in the demo app.

Comment: The requirement to build the child is a requirement of the `fields_for`. The same way you need to have `@model = Model.new` in your new action, you then need to initialize at least one of the children. Ya I had no idea either until my supervisor told me about it when I had to start working with cocoon and nested fields in general.

Comment: Hi, this is not what I would expect. You do not even have to explicitly build a new child item in the controller. When rendering the `link_to_add_new_associaction` a new child is created (server-side). Can you either show us some code or check out the demo-project https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo. If you suspect this is a bug, please open an issue on the cocoon github.

Comment: Hi Nathan:  Many thanks for your feedback.  Happy to open an issue if this turns out to be a bug.  I suspect not. Currently, I'm leaning toward the idea that my jQuery setup is not correct.  I'll update the question with the code.

Comment: The only real obvious differences I found that are suspect would be 
    a) that my new view doesn't include a separate form partial (seems unlikely)
    b) the parent model has dependent_destroy enabled for the child models

Comment: Hmmm...started debugging the gem.  Put byebug in the link_to_add_competition method.  The code stops when the page is loaded the first time (as I'd expect) but if I click the Add Child link, there is no response in the rails console. From the comments in the code, shouldn't I expect a server side model to be created when the link is clicked?  @nathanvda

Comment: Following on from there, adding another call to byebug in the create_object method also gets called when the form is built the first time, but clicking the Add Child button also has no effect in the rails console.

Comment: Hi @BrendanO'Brien great you found your answer! To explain how cocoon works: the form and the about-to-be-inserted child-form/partial are all rendered server-side. Client side the form is built, so when the `link_to_add_association` is clicked, a pre-rendered child-partial is duplicated, manipulated a little (mainly to have unique id's) and then inserted into the html. So no server calls are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh!  What a facepalm moment.  Turned out the `<a>` tag on the ckeditor description field caused all this fuss.  Removing the `<a>` tag allowed cocoon to operate normally.

So, in answer to the original question: No, the cocoon gem does -not- require even one child model to be built in the new controller action to add them.